# 360 Degree Image View by Scrubbing mp4 in video tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, html5-video, mp4

I'm trying to replicate a 360° image viewer experience using a video. The goal is to let users click and drag on a video to fast forward or rewind it, simulating the effect of spinning a 3D object.

Here's the current jQuery implementation I'm using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    let video = $('#product-video')[0];
    let isDragging = false;
    let initialClientX, initialTime, currentX;

    const sensitivity = 0.005;

    function updateVideoTime() {
        if (!isDragging) return;

        const deltaX = currentX - initialClientX;
        video.currentTime = initialTime + (video.duration * (deltaX * sensitivity));

        // Ensure currentTime remains within bounds
        video.currentTime = Math.max(0, Math.min(video.currentTime, video.duration));

        requestAnimationFrame(updateVideoTime);
    }

    $('#product-video').on('mousedown', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        isDragging = true;
        initialClientX = e.clientX;
        initialTime = video.currentTime;

        requestAnimationFrame(updateVideoTime);
    });

    $(document).on('mousemove', function(e) {
        if (isDragging) {
            currentX = e.clientX;
        }
    }).on('mouseup', function() {
        isDragging = false;
    });
});
```

While the video does update as I drag, it doesn't feel like it's updating in near real-time. There's a noticeable lag between the mouse movement and the video update. I'd like to make the video scrubbing as smooth as possible to mimic the effect of a 360° viewer.

Is there a more efficient way to update the video's playback position more frequently to achieve this real-time scrubbing effect?